# opengeo suite sdk gxp EPSG

Tags: boundless-suite, epsg, sdk, gxp

I am working in a viewer with suite sdk gxp and I can see my layers, but some of them in the viewer are located wrong. I have checked postgis and geoserver and every layer is ok with the same EPSG, 4326. Any idea about this?

Comment: How far off are they? If they're off a few to a few hundred meters, they could be using a different geographic coordinate reference system aka datum. If further away, could be in a different projected coordinate reference system.

Comment: They are far away to the right position, but not all of them, some of my layers are well located. And I cheked it them with Qgis, and the CRS is Ok!!

Comment: I have a geotiff image as a background, Can it be the problem?

Comment: The ones that are in the wrong location may have the wrong CRS definition. Did you "redefine" the CRS on some of them, without actually reprojecting them?

Comment: Thank you for your help!!
I didn't reprojecting because they are geting from the database, so I understand that they are in the right CRS. 
The thing is, in some of the layers when they are snown with some double features or elements ( doble line in diferent position), one in the right position and the other no.
I think that I am going to reload my layers in the Postgis-Postgres and restart to be sure.

Comment: Also, if you do zoom in, the layer in some situations is well reprojected!!! Any idea? Can be any about Tile Caching?